# Node js, how to compare two results from sql queries?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, callback

my objective is to compare two sql results, i have tried a lot of things, and I have come up to the use of callbacks, and my first idea was to create a list to store the two callbacks in the first argument and second argument of the list, and then compare them, but it doesn't, i am open to any solution, my objective is just to compare the results from the sql queries, my code is as follows :

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
   
   
   
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "espace_membre"
});
   
 var pseudo1 = "amine";
       
var socketid = '3485858585';
   
var peerId = '4444';
  


// 1. Call helloCatAsync passing a callback function,
//    which will be called receiving the result from the async operation
console.log("1. function called...")
helloCatAsync(function(result) {
    // 5. Received the result from the async function,
    //    now do whatever you want with it:
 
 var Finale = [];
 
 // console.log("5. result is: ", result);
 
Finale.push(result);

console.log(Finale);
 

 

});

// 2. The "callback" parameter is a reference to the function which
//    was passed as argument from the helloCatAsync call
function helloCatAsync(callback) {
    console.log("2. callback here is the function passed as argument above...")
    // 3. Start async operation:
    setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("3. start async operation...")
    console.log("4. finished async operation, calling the callback, passing the result...")
        // 4. Finished async operation,
        //    call the callback passing the result as argument
  con.connect(function(err) {
    
  con.query("SELECT gender FROM gender WHERE socketid = '" + peerId + "'", function (err, result) {
      
 
   
 

    callback(result);
   
  });
});

 con.connect(function(err) {

  con.query("SELECT gender FROM gender WHERE socketid = '" + socketid + "'", function (err, result) {
 
    callback(result);
 
  

  });
});
       
    }, Math.random() * 2000);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about where any comparison is actually happening. All I see are two queries.

Comment: hi, my objective is to do the comparison, and for that i am trying to create a list, to use it to compare, i haven't done the comparison yet, i am trying to get the tools to compare ( result and result1), thus creating the list.